# Equipment/Computer Budgets for CS PhD Students

Tags: funding, computer-science

I plan on attending graduate school in computer science next year (fall 2020 semester).

In a computer science (or related field like software engineering) PhD program, is it standard to furnish graduate students with a "work computer", separate from a personal laptop purchased out of pocket, for conducting research?

I want to know if I'll have to shell out some cash for a beefier laptop or if computing resources are usually provided. If so, what computing resources are available (either as cash/budgeted money or as computers PhD students can use), and where does the funding usually come from?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: What do you think you'll need a beefy laptop for? I did most of my PhD thesis on an old Optiplex desktop with Linux on it. I'm guessing unless you won't actually need that much computing power unless you specialize in GPU programming or something.

Comment: @Buffy I'm located in the U.S.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I did an REU (research experience for undergraduates, a program for US undergraduates interested in research, funded by the NSF), and some program attendees did some fairly heavy work on their personal laptops; I was able to work remotely. We were not provided with separate personal computers for the program. We did also have access to a cluster as well. Because I haven't yet entered graduate school, I wasn't quite sure how computing resources worked when one is a graduate student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on my experience in France and Ireland. I would assume that it's similar at least in other European countries [please edit or comment if I'm wrong].

In computer science PhD students are usually provided with everything they need to do their work including (at least) a desktop computer, office space, and generally there is also a budget for traveling to conferences. Depending on the country they might have the status of staff member or not, but even if not the working conditions are very similar to those one would expect in a regular job (well, an academic job, don't expect too much!).

The budget related to equipment/travel is usually a part of the PhD funding which is given to the institution, as opposed to the main funding which is a grant or salary given to the PhD student. The budget for traveling/accommodation is usually the most limited part, it might even happen that there's no budget at all for this. It's a good idea to ask the supervisor about it at the beginning in order to submit papers to conferences in a sensible way: it's a shame to have a paper accepted but find oneself unable to attend the conference.

PS: in terms of computer equipment, in computer science it's also common to be provided with an access to some kind of high performance cluster.